# Pasting causes VBA to behave illogically

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

My code is really simple:

```
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
k = 2

For i = 0 To PatientList.ListCount - 1
    If PatientList.Selected(i) = True Then
        Worksheets("Print").Range("B" & k).Value = 1
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i
Unload Me
```

For some reason, if I remove the line that contains (Worksheets.......) and have a multiselected listBox the `k` variable is incremented normally and all is fine. 
If I add the aforementioned line, the program goes through the cycle once as if only one line on the listbox is selected. The `k` variable is not incremented and setting toggle shows that the program doesn't not recognize the multiselection, but only the first choice.

Any ideas?
This is very odd and I tested on different PCs....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199480/discussion-on-question-by-dimitris-platis-pasting-causes-vba-to-behave-illogical).

Answer (score 0):

since it seems your ListBox `RowSource` value is influenced by any change of "Print" worksheet, you could collect the range to be copied/pasted and do the copy/paste operation at the end

```
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
k = 2

Dim rngToBeCopied As Range ' range to collect cells to copy

For i = 0 To PatientList.ListCount - 1
    If PatientList.Selected(i) = True Then

        ' update range to be copied
        If rngToBeCopied Is Nothing Then
            Set rngToBeCopied = Worksheets("Source").Cells(k, 1)
        Else
            Set rngToBeCopied = Union(rngToBeCopied, Worksheets("Source").Cells(k, 1))
        End If

        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i


' if any range to copy, then paste it to "Print" worksheet
If Not rngToBeCopied Is Nothing Then rngToBeCopied.Copy Worksheets("Print").Range("B1").Resize(rngToBeCopied.Count)

Me.Hide ' hide UserForm
' Unload Me ' move 'Unload' statement in the sub that has created/shown the Userform
```

just change `Worksheets("Source").Cells(k, 1)` to the proper sheet and range reference you actualy need

Comment: Thanks people.....I just erased the contents of the previous file that worked and re-constructed my Userforms and it seems to work. 
No obvious connection btw the rowsource could be found in the file that didnt work. This is very odd.....but in a way classic!

Comment: In further study, the problem was related to cells within the rowsource. 
In fact, there was an "Age" column that calculated age based on another column within the row source. 
Once this column was deleted the problem disappeared!